# Can we write each number between $1$ and $n$ in one of the forms $2^j, \ 2^j+1, \ \ldots , \ 2^{j+1}-1$?

Tags: analysis

I want to find a natural number $n$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\geq \frac{15}{1.1}$$

There is a hint, but I don't really know how to use this.

Hint : Write together the terms of the sum with $k=2^j, \  2^j+1, \ \ldots , \ 2^{j+1}-1$, $\ j\in \mathbb{N}_0$ give an upper bound for these.

So can we write each number between $1$ and $n$ in one of the forms $2^j, \  2^j+1, \ \ldots , \ 2^{j+1}-1$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Do we find it as follows?

\begin{equation*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_k\geq 15 \Rightarrow r\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\geq 15\Rightarrow 1.1\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\geq 15 \Rightarrow  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\geq \frac{15}{1.1} \end{equation*}

It holds that \begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots \\ & \geq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots\\ & =1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots\end{align*}
Für jedes $j\in \mathbb{N}_0$ folgt dann dass \begin{equation*} \sum _{k=1}^{2^{j}}{\frac {1}{k}}\geq 1+{\frac {j}{2}}\end{equation*}
So we find the smallest $j$ such that $1+{\frac {j}{2}}\geq \frac{15}{1.1} \Rightarrow j\geq 2\cdot \left (\frac{15}{1.1}-1\right ) \Rightarrow j\geq 25.27$.

So the minimum result is $2^{26}$.

Comment: Did you try doing it? Say for $j\leq 4$ for instance?

Comment: We have for $j=0$ : $1,2, 3, 4, ... $. For $j=1$ : $2, 3, 4, 5, ...$ . For $j=2$ : $4, 5, 6, ...$, etc, right? @CaptainLama

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence) would help.

Comment: So do we write that in this way : $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n} \\ \geq 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^j}$$  @player3236

Comment: Could you please take a look at the edit part of my post above? @player3236

Comment: Could you please take a look at the edit part of my post above?@CaptainLama

Comment: I won't say $2^{26}$ is the minimum, but it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what that are trying to say is

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k = \sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k + .......  + \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1} \frac 1k + ......$

and to consider what $\sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}} \frac 1k$.  As $2^j \le k < 2^{j+1}$ then $\frac 1{2^{j+1}} < \frac 1k \le \frac 1{2^j}$ and $2^j\cdot \frac 1{2^{j+1}} < \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}} \frac 1k \le 2^j\cdot \frac 1{2^j}$ and we can conclude that $\frac 12 < \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}} \frac 1k \le 1$.

Can you continue?

This assumes that if $2^m \le n < 2^{m+1}$ then

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k = \sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k +  ......+  \sum_{k=2^{m-1}}^{2^{m}-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^m}^n \frac 1k$.

And so

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k +  ......+  \sum_{k=2^{m-1}}^{2^{m}-1} \frac 1k \le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \le \sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k +  ......+  \sum_{k=2^{m-1}}^{2^{m}-1} \frac 1k$

$\frac 12 + \frac 12 +....+\frac 12 < \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \le 1+1+ 1+...... + 1$

$\frac m2 < \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \le m+1$

Anyhoo.   If $\frac m2 \ge \frac {15}{1.1}$ then $m\ge \frac {30}{1.1} > 27$.

So if $n = 2^{28}$ then that should be large enough.  After all...

$\frac 11 + $

$\frac 12 +  $

$\frac 13 +\frac 14 +$

$\frac 15 + \frac 16 + \frac 17 + \frac 18 + $

$\frac 19 + .... + \frac 1{16} + $

......

$\frac 1{2^{27}+ 1} + \frac 1{2^{27}+2} + .... + \frac 1{2^{28}} >$

$1 +$

$\frac 12+$

$2\cdot \frac14+$

$4\cdot \frac18+$

$8\cdot \frac 1{16}+$

$...... $

$2^{27}\cdot \frac 1{2^{28}} =$

$1 +\frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + \frac 12 + ..... + \frac 12 = 1+ 28\frac 12 = 1 + 14 = 15 > \frac {15}{1.1}$.

.....

But I feel I am being a bit ham fisted.  were we expected to find a tighter range?

Comment: At $$\sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k +  ......+  \sum_{k=2^{m-1}}^{2^{m}-1} \frac 1k \le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \le \sum_{k=1}^{2^1-1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^1}^{2^2 -1} \frac 1k + \sum_{k=2^2}^{2^3 -1} \frac 1k +  ......+  \sum_{k=2^{m+1}}^{2^{m}-1} \frac 1k$$ is the last term correct?

Comment: I  mean... is it correct that $k$ goes from $2^{m+1}$ to $2^m-1$ ?

Comment: No... that was a typo.  Note though that $ 2^{k+1}- 1 =  2^k + (\color{blue}{2^k-1})$.

Comment: But isn't ther upper bound $2^{m+1}-1$ ?

Comment: To get back to you *VERY* first question.  For every $n\ge1$ there is a  $j= \lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$ so that $2^j \le n < 2^{j+1}$.  Therefore, we *can* always write $n = 2^j + k$ where $0\le k < 2^j$ but letting $k = n-2^j$.

Comment: "But isn't ther upper bound 2m+1−1 ?" I don't know what this is in reference to.  This is a guideline.  You can fit $n$ to be between $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$ and use that to prove $\sum \frac 1k$ diverges and that for all $M$ you can find an $n$ so that $\sum \frac 1k > M$ by figuring out that $m$ and tweaking $n$ to be somewhere based on $2^m$.  ....  But I leave all the ironing out and all the details to you.

Comment: Does it hold for each natural number $n$ that it is between $2^m$ and $2^{m+1}$ ?

Comment: It does not hold that $27$ is between $2^{8}=256$ and $2^9=512$  but it *does* hold that $27$ is between $2^4=16$ and $2^5=32$.  As $1 < 2 < 4 < 8 < 16 < 32 <......$ is unbounded every natural number will fit between $2^m \le n < 2^{m+1}$ for *some* $m$.  For example for $27: 16 < 27 < 32$ and $27 = 16+11$ and for $834:  512 < 834 < 1024$ and $834 = 512+322$ and for $758493692:  2^{29}<758493692 <2^{30}$ and $758493692 = 2^{29} + (758493692-2^{29})$.

Comment: Let $n$ but any integer.  Let $m = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$ so $m= \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor \le \log_2 n <  \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1 = m+1$.  So $2^m\le 2^{\log_2 n} = n < 2^{m+1}$.  And so $0 \le n - 2^m < 2^{m+1} -2^m = 2^m$.  So if we let $k = n-2^m$ we always can always express $n$ as $n = 2^m + k; 0\le k < 2^m$.   .... This should be basic.  For any $n$ se if $1\le n < 2$.  If not try $2\le n < 4$. If not try $4 \le n < 8$.  If not tre $8 \le n < 16$ and so on.... keep going.... eventually you will *have* to find $2^m \le n < 2^{m+1}$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)